# Query information about a file android

Tags: android, file, cursor

For a content: URI, I used ContentProvider/Contentresolver to retrieve information about the modified date, size and data. I would like to do the same for file: URI but when I try the following code:

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, proj, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
```

Cursor is returned as null. How to get the file size, data and date added/modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but you use java's normal file IO to find that information.

Here is an example of me finding out that information for a picture called cat.jpg:

```
File f = new File("/data/cat.jpg");

//Size of file in bytes
Long size = f.length();

//Time of when the file was last modified in microseconds
Long lastModified = f.lastModified();

//The bytes of the file. This gets populated below
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)f.length()];

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    int offset = 0;
    int bytesActuallyRead;

    while( (bytesActuallyRead = fis.read(fileData, offset, 1024)) > 0) {
        offset += bytesActuallyRead;
    }

} catch(Exception e) {

}
```